# Regular Expression Remove all English and Arabic numbers?

Tags: regex, unicode, preg-replace, preg-match

I want Regular Expression to remove Arabic and english numbers

my varibale is
$variable="12121212ABDHSتشؤآئ۳۳۴۳۴729384234owiswoisw";

i want remove all digits ! LIKE:

**ABDHSتشؤآئowiswoisw**

I found the following expression but not work !

```
 $newvariable = preg_replace('/^[\u0621-\u064A]+$', '', $variable);
```

thanks for you helps

Comment: You may  use  `'/\d+/u'`

Comment: Not work : https://regex101.com/r/5ww0tB/1

Comment: The `'/\d+/u'` does - https://regex101.com/r/5ww0tB/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$newvariable = preg_replace('/\d+/u', '', $variable);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ww0tB/2)

The `\d` matches ASCII digits by default, but when you add the `u` modifier, it enables the `PCRE_UCP` option (together with `PCRE_UTF8`) that enables `\d` to match all Unicode digits.

See [PCRE documentation](https://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> This option changes the way PCRE processes \B, \b, \D, \d, \S, \s,  \W,
>   \w,  and  some  of  the POSIX character classes. By default, only ASCII
>   characters are recognized, but if PCRE_UCP is set,  Unicode  properties
>   are  used instead to classify characters.

You may fix your regex if you need to only restrict matching to ASCII and those of your choice:

```
preg_replace('/[0-9\u0621-\u064A]+/u', '', $variable)
```